# Atribuir valores a arrays

Tags: javascript, array

Percebi que ao incrementar um valor a um `array` usando a seguinte sintaxe:

```
let array = [];
array['nomeIndice'] = 10;
```

o `length` desse `array` não é incrementado, e continua em `0`, apesar do `array` conter um item. Qual o motivo desse comportamento?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript tem algumas coisas confusas, uma delas é que o que você está usando é oficialmente chamado de *array*, mas na prática é uma tabela *hash*, um dicionário, ou até pode-se chamar de *array* associativo.

Só é *array* tem um `length`. Mas ele se comporta como um dicionário esta propriedade não funciona porque não há um comprimento oficial, embora tecnicamente seria possível manter algo assim, há outras questão mal formuladas no JS que dificulta isso.

De certa forma um *array* desse tipo é igual a um objeto, é considerado que ele tem membros e não elementos, por isso uma contagem não faria sentido.

A solução para isto é apanhar só as chaves ou só os valores em um *array* e pegar o tamanho dele. Tem [função pronta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) que faz isso. Assim:

```js
let array = [];
array['nomeIndice'] = 10;
console.log(Object.keys(array).length);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/AddElementImplicitly.js).

Answer (score 4):

Só para acrescentar mais um pouco de informação ao que o @Maniero já disse, se você utilizar indices numéricos continua a utilizar o array como sendo um array normal.

Veja com o índice `10` por exemplo:

```js
let array = [];
console.log(array, array.length);

array[10] = 2;
console.log(array, array.length);
```

Aqui vê que ao definir a posição `10` com um valor, todas as posições anteriores foram definidas com `undefined` e no final o array ficou com tamanho `11`.

Mas quando atribui um índice não numérico já se comporta como se fosse um dicionário com chaves e valores, não aparecendo essa informação no local onde apareceria num array:

```js
let array = [];
console.log(array, array.length);

array['nomeIndice'] = 2;
console.log(array, array.length);

console.log(array['nomeIndice']);
```

Mas repare que acedendo à chave `'nomeIndice'` o valor está lá na mesma.

A sintaxe mais correta para isto é mesmo a de objeto com `{}`, que torna evidente que está a lidar com chaves e valores, e não de um array em que normalmente acrescentaria valores através de [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) sem especificar a posição:

```js
let objeto = {};
console.log(objeto);

objeto['nomeIndice'] = 2;
console.log(objeto);
```

Answer (score 0):

O correto seria:

`let array = [];
array[i] = 10;`

Você pode usar o método `push(quaquer tipo de elemento)` para adicionar elementos no array, desta forma:

`array.push(10);`

Comment: Acho que isto não responde o que ele perguntou.